# WM_SETFOCUS message and NULL wParam

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I've a simple Win32 Windows app with a single, main  window. Inside the `window procedure` I'd like to investigate a `WM_SETFOCUS` message. The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-setfocus) says:

> A handle to the window that has lost the keyboard focus. This
> parameter can be NULL.

This is my case - I'm getting just NULL. What does it mean and why dont I get a handle to for e.g the desktop when the desktop was a previos top, active window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32-bit Windows introduced an asynchronous input model. One consequence of this change is that the focus window is now recorded per thread (or input-attached group of threads).

Initially, a thread attached to an input queue doesn't have a focus window, so the first time a program sees a `WM_SETFOCUS` message, its `wParam` is `NULL`. There are other reasons why `WM_SETFOCUS` can have `NULL` as its parameter, but those aren't interesting here.

---

Bonus reading:

- [Eventually, nothing is special any more](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081006-00/?p=20643)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Raymond post.